# Create objects in unreal engine?

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4

I have to create object like this:

```
UStaticMeshComponent* staticMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("CustomStaticMesh"));
```

But I don't get how this works. Why do I add that angle bracket? I understand it has to do with templates but can't find the syntax for using template this way,

and is CreateDefaultSubobject a static function so I can call it without instantiating?

Comment: It’s a templated function; the angle-bracket is c-++’s syntax for supplying a template-argument.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateDefaultSubObject` is only to be used inside of Constructors.

Use `NewObject` or in the case of an AActor derived class `UWorld::SpawnActor` to create these objects respectively outside of the constructor, typically at runtime.

The `<>` denotes the template type passed to the function.